# What is it called: anti-insect sliding door & anti-insect sliding window?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Look at the picture below,

Normally, people have normal sliding doors made of glass or wood or whatever. And to prevent insects from flying into the house, people often add another layers of 
of net-screen sliding doors like the picture below.

[image]

And they also do that for sliding windows as well, like in this picture

[image]

Do we have a common term for them?

**anti-insect sliding door & anti-insect sliding window?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not aware of a common term. In the southern U.S., we might refer to the door as a **sliding door** or possibly a **screen door**. Both are ambiguous because they might be made of glass or screen material. A screen door could also be a hinged door or a sliding glass door. You’ll sometimes hear the latter called a **sliding glass door**. Likewise, we’ll call a screen in a window a **window screen** or just a **screen**.